# Call a method of an Activity from a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am making an app that has a slightly different UI in `tablets` and `smartphones`. In tablets, it displays two fragments side-by-side. The events in the fragment on the left cause a video to be displayed in the fragment on the right.

This is good for tablets. In case of phone,I will have one fragment on screen and I need to display a `DialogFragment` where the video will be played. Since the main activity acts as a relay for communication between the fragments, I have made a boolean named `isXHDPI` which will let me know which layout was inflated (the one for phone or for tablets) and will be set to true only when the tablet layout is inflated and let me display things properly.

The question is: How do I call the method `setIsXHDPI()` of `MainActivity` from a fragment ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html. check the topic communicating with activity. you need to use interface. code snippet is  also shown

Comment: Just a quick fix: Can you make setIsXHDPI as static and call it like MainActivity.setIsXHDPI()

Comment: @Hari Using `getActivity()` in the fragment, you mean? :)

Comment: @Hari http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html. they don't use static

Comment: No, MainActivity is a Java Class right? so Java Syntax allows you to call a static method using the class name only (like you call Integer.parseInt()). I mean it that way. I dont know whether it fits your requirement.

Comment: @Raghunandan Oh, I dont know that. Thanks for clarrification. I just suggested that as a quick fix since I usually (NOT ALWAYS) use static functions in such situations.